# How to change account in Steam-version of AirMech?

Tags: steam, airmech

Few years ago, I created AirMech account on its Chrome app using Google oAuth. I played it for a while making a nice progress in it.

Yesterday, I downloaded AirMech beta from Steam and hit *Create Account* by mistake instead of *Login* (I did forget about my old account). I was just asked for username (no email or password).

Now, I want to use my old account. After unable to find logout or change account option, I even removed local content and re-downloaded the game again using Steam. But, the game is automatically logging in with new username.

How to change account in steam-version of AirMech?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look around for you and found the following thread:
https://www.carbongames.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=8518

According to this, there is currently no way for the user themselves to unlink an account on Steam. It seems the account gets linked to your steam id, so that is why removing local content or re-downloading doesn't help address the issue.

Seems the friendly guys at Carbon Games will help you unlink an account.

Try emailing support@carbongames.com with your steam id and account names and they should be able to unlink the wrong account and link the right account for you.

Your steam id can be easily retrieved using this website: http://steamidconverter.com/
Put in your custom url of your steam account (in my case it is lyrical) and it will return your steam id.

Hope that helps and you get it resolved.

Comment: Carbon Games support has merged my old account upon request. For this, they took exactly 1 week.

Comment: Great to hear that you got it resolved.